# what's difference in given LINQ to collection query?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I am pretty confused in collection and IEnumerable types. Can any one explain why the 1st query is wrong but the 2nd is correct-
**1st- this gives error**

```
ConditionFieldCollection conditionColl = (ConditionFieldCollection)Session["ConditionFieldCollection"];
ConditionFieldCollection cnd = new ConditionFieldCollection(); 
cnd = (from c in conditionColl
            where iq.QueryField == c.Expression
                select c);
```

**2nd - works fine**

```
ConditionFieldCollection conditionColl = (ConditionFieldCollection)Session["ConditionFieldCollection"];
List<ConditionField> cnd = (from c in conditionColl.OfType<ConditionField>()
                                       where iq.QueryField == c.Expression
                                       select c).ToList();
```

**I know LINQ returns IEnumerable type of collection object but ConditionFieldCollection is also a Collection then why it gives me error at compile time. Is there any difference b/w Collecton and IEnumerable Collection??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to assign an `IEnumerable<ConditionField>` to a variable with type `ConditionFieldCollection` - that can't work. An enumerable is not a collection, and certainly isn't that *specific* collection.

Many collections allow an enumerable constructor, so this may work:

```
ConditionFieldCollection cnd = new ConditionFieldCollection(
    from c in conditionColl
    where iq.QueryField == c.Expression
    select c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because `ConditionFieldCollection` is a collection does not mean it is the same collection as the return value from the query.

It is like saying

```
class Mammal{}
class Dog : Mammal {}
class Cat : Mammal {}

Dog d = new Dog();
Cat c = new Cat();
d = c; // Wrong, even though they are both mammals they are not the same kind of mammal.
```

**Edit**
Depending on how `ConditionFieldCollection` works you may have two options, hopefully at least one of them works.

**1**

```
ConditionFieldCollection cnd = new ConditionFieldCollection(); 
cnd.AddRange(from c in conditionColl
             where iq.QueryField == c.Expression
             select c);
```

**2**

```
ConditionFieldCollection cnd = 
    new ConditionFieldCollection(from c in conditionColl
                                 where iq.QueryField == c.Expression
                                 select c);
```